# How do I copy the 4 latest files from a password-protected online directory to another directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file

As a preface, I am a complete noob at batch file processing (which I am assuming is the way to achieve what I'm trying to do). I have done extensive searching on this subject, but the answers given only help me partially.

I work with our HRIS each morning to upload 4 files it produces into our payroll system. They are not all created at the exact same time, but roughly in the same minute and I would like to copy all 4 of these files to a new location. I can't go by file name, because the files change names every day.

**The Main Question:**
How can I script a way to copy the **4** latest files from a password protected directory (not just the latest file) to a new directory? (Another possibility would be to copy all files created on the day the script is run)

The code I found that seems closest is below, but it is only the latest single file, when I would like to copy multiple files.

```
    :Variables
    SET DatabaseBackupPath=\\virtualserver1\Database Backups

    echo.
    echo Restore WebServer Database
    FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "%DatabaseBackupPath%\WebServer\*.bak" /B /O:D') DO SET NewestFile=%%I
    copy "%DatabaseBackupPath%\WebServer\%NewestFile%" "D:\"

    sqlcmd -U <username> -P <password> -d master -Q ^
    "RESTORE DATABASE [ExampleDatabaseName] ^
    FROM  DISK = N'D:\%NewestFile%' ^
    WITH  FILE = 1,  ^
    MOVE N'Example_CS' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Example.mdf',  ^
    MOVE N'Example_CS_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Example_1.LDF',  ^
    NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10"
```

I hope this makes sense, and I appreciate your responses.

Comment: `forfiles /p "C:\payrolldir" /f *.txt /d 0 /c "cmd /c copy "@path" "\\payrollserver\share\folder"` will copy all text files from today. See `forfiles /?`. Schedule it with Task Scheduler. See `Schtasks /?`.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out. The directory is protected by a password - will this piece of script allow me to add the credentials? I'm extremely new to this. Sorry if it's an obvious answer.

Comment: There is no such thing as a password protected directory.

Comment: The directory in question is on a password protected server - and the files go into a mapped network folder. For example, when I double click this folder, it asks me for a user/pass (which I have). I can't copy or paste files from this location without it. Hopefully that clarifies a bit.

Comment: You should be added to the security for the folder or share. It's not password protected, you don't have access (or if you are an admin, your access in in your other token - Normal or As Admin token). We don't have any concept of password protection in Windows - everything is from your logon. You can use `net use` to map a drive. See `net use /?`.

Comment: Perhaps I am getting the terminology wrong. The location where the data is held on our webhost's server (Added through Add Network Location through the mapping tool in Windows). Windows 7 requires me to put in a password every day to access this folder (this was not originally the case in XP, where I only ever needed to enter it once).

I apologize if I'm not explaining myself well enough.

Comment: Wrap your script in the runas command. See `runas /?`. This allows you to specify passwords ifit's using Windows Authenication.

Answer (score 0):

alright, i have a code that is a litle bit goofy,
what i do is making a temporary folder.
now i **move** your latest file into that temporary folder and i repeat this action 4 times.
After that's done, i move the complete temp folder to your d drive

**This code**  is a replacement of the original code between line 6 and 8

```
if not exist "%DatabaseBackupPath%\WebServer\temp" md "%DatabaseBackupPath%\WebServer\temp"

for /l %%a in (1,1,4) do (

 FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "%DatabaseBackupPath%\WebServer\*.bak" /B  /O:D') DO (
SET NewestFile=%%I
move "%DatabaseBackupPath%\WebServer\%NewestFile%" "%DatabaseBackupPath%\WebServer\temp\"
)
)
for /r "%DatabaseBackupPath%\WebServer\temp" %%b in (*.*) do (
       move "%%b" "D:\"
)
```

i hope this helped you